# Software to block specific internet web pages

Tags: software-recommendation, parental-controls

I am looking to download some software on an old laptop that runs the Ubuntu Operating System on it.  The software that I am interested in is something that will allow me to block specific internet web pages.  Does anyone know of any such software for the Ubuntu system?

Comment: Web pages or websites? Do you have a list of ones to block or do you wish to block based on content?

Comment: dan08 - I am looking to block certain content.

Comment: any suggestions?

Comment: Never used any of this, but this is the first Google result: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ParentalControls

Comment: I think your question is too broad as you have several options and you have not described what or how you want to filter.

Comment: @bain - depends, OP could be looking for adblock , the question is not the best.

Answer (score 2):

There are several options, depending on what and how you are trying to filter.

1 -If you simply wish to filter most "adult content" sites you can use opendns . Opendsn is easy to set up and they will do most of the work for you (maintaining blacklists)

http://www.opendns.com/home-internet-security/parental-controls/opendns-home/

2 - You can download a blacklist of ip addresses from the internet and use iptables or your hosts file to block ip. This is sort of difficult in that you have to update the list from time to time.

3 - If you want to filter content, you can use a proxy. My favorites are privoxy and squid.

See http://www.techradar.com/us/news/software/applications/6-of-the-best-content-filters-for-linux-698307#articleContent for ideas.

4 - You can use addins or plugins, adblock for firefox for example.